# match variable to list based on variable name

Tags: python

I have list of strings 'columns' and corresponding data outcome 'data'.
how can I iterate through data and check if my variables have same values as values in data list?

```
columns = ["username", "email", "admin", "alive"]
data = ("john", "john@snow.com", "True", "True")

username = "john"
email = "different@email.com"
admin = False
alive = True
```

I would like to get an output like: `["same", "different", "different", "same"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was looking for simple eval().

so simple:

```
for i in data:
  if i == eval(columns[data.index(i)]):
    print("it's the same")
```

did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
data = ("john", "john@snow.com", True, True)
check_list = [username,email,admin,alive]
output = ['same' if i == j else 'diffrent' for i,j in zip(data,check_list)]
```

**Output**

> ['same', 'diffrent', 'diffrent', 'same']

Comment: Thanks! this is assuming that check_list is NOT list of strings but references to variables. Any posibility to do it with `check_list = ["username","email","admin","alive"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ("john", "john@snow.com", "True", "True")
# create a dict with key and values
# its about readability
input_data = {"username":"john",
              "email" :"different@email.com",
              "admin" : False,
              "alive" : True}

match_list = {}

for expected, (k,v) in zip(data, input_data.items()):
  if expected != str(v):
    match_list[k] = "different"
  else:
    match_list[k] = "same"

for k,v in match_list.items():
  print (k,v)

#your expected answer ["same", "different", "different", "same"]
#is ok but not really useful....
#now you will get a key for your diff

username same
email different
alive same
admin different
```

Comment: thx! but in your case you are just comparing 2 lists/dicts layed up nicely to each other. My case is that I have variables spreaded out in code, and I want to ask for those variables based on 'columns'. 'columns' can change, user can add another column so I want automatically ask for yet another variable from my code

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid having to do this, you should.  If you can't avoid it, you can look up the values of variables by name in `locals()`

Your code:

```
columns = ["username", "email", "admin", "alive"]
data = ("john", "john@snow.com", "True", "True")

username = "john"
email = "different@email.com"
admin = False
alive = True
```

To get your desired output:

```
['same' if str(i) == str(locals()[j]) else 'different' for i,j in zip(data, columns)]
```

> ['same', 'different', 'different', 'same']

The calls to `str` are needed because `"True"` and `True` are not the same.